# Can't determine the cause of NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

I have this following class which is a shopping cart class and is coded to display the contents of the shopping cart. The products are displayed in a linear layout with product infos in textViews and a corresponding button to remove the product and are arranged horizontally in linearlayout. View elements are created dynamically. My apps runs well until this class is called. Then the app crashes and LogCat gives a `Java.lang.NullPointerException` error at `"lb.addView(ll)"` line.I don't know why this is happening. Someone please help me out to solve This.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Secondscreen extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.secondscreen); 

        //TextView showCartContent          = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showCart);
        final    Button       thirdBtn    = (Button) findViewById(R.id.third);
        final    LinearLayout lb          = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearMain);
        final    Controller   aController = (Controller) getApplicationContext();
        final    int          cartSize    = aController.getCart().getCartSize();
        //String                showString  = "";

        if(cartSize > 0){   
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 

            for(int i = 0; i < cartSize; i++) {
                // Get product data from product data arraylist
                String pName  = aController.getCart().getProducts(i).getProductName();
                int    pPrice = aController.getCart().getProducts(i).getProductPrice();
                String pDisc  = aController.getCart().getProducts(i).getProductDesc();

                // Create LinearLayout to view elements
                LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
                ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);             

                TextView product = new TextView(this);
                product.setText(" " + pName + "    ");

                // Add textView to LinearLayout
                ll.addView(product);

                TextView productdesc = new TextView(this);
                product.setText(" " + pDisc + "    ");

                // Add textView to LinearLayout
                ll.addView(productdesc);

                TextView price = new TextView(this);
                price.setText("  $" + pPrice + "     ");

                // Add textView to LinearLayout
                ll.addView(price);

                final Button btn = new Button(this);
                btn.setId(i + 1);
                btn.setText("Remove from Cart");

                // set the layoutParams on the button
                btn.setLayoutParams(params);
                final int index = i;

                //Create click listener for dynamically created button
                btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // Get product instance for index
                        ModelProducts tempProductObject = aController.getCart().getProducts(index);
                        aController.getCart().removeProducts(tempProductObject);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Products Removed \n Now Cart size: "+ aController.getCart().getCartSize(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

                // Add button to LinearLayout
                ll.addView(btn);

                // Add LinearLayout to XML layout
                lb.addView(ll);
            }
        }

        thirdBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(cartSize > 0) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Thirdscreen.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                } else
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Shopping cart is empty.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    } 

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: please show `secondscreen.xml`

Comment: Have you debugged and looked at the value of ll and lb? Is one of those null?

Comment: point that line where you are getting null

Comment: lb is obviously null: findViewById(R.id.linearMain) returns null. You have to double check, whether the linearMain view really exists. For further help, you need to provide the xml-file where this id is defined.

Comment: please post XML and logcat for us to determine the nullpointer

Comment: Thanks everyone, I have sort out the problem. you were right I have assigned an id which was not in the secondscreen.xml file. That is why the null pointer exception was shown. I should have noticed that. Anyways thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your `lb` is null because the call of

```
final LinearLayout lb          = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearMain);
```

didn't find it by id as you expected.

Comment: Thanks for the solution Alexey Malev. The problem was exactly what you stated above.

Answer (score 0):

Please check you have not created ambiguity while  creating views this could cuase a problem if you tried to define view with same ids